# PHP User authentication Logic

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to understand how I can setup the right logic for what I'm trying to do.

I want to have a site that gives access to specific URLs based on the user type/category. So if User A subscribed to URLs 1,2,3 he should not be able to access 4,5,6 which User B has subscribed to.

I can easily write something that would check to see if a user is logged in before populating a series of links, but I dont want the links to be shared with other users.

I was thinking I might use a mysql query to select from where a user would match a certain group or type and put this query in every page so before loading the content it would check the db to make sure the right user is getting access to it.

What I want to know is 1. Is this the right method to do this? and 2. How would I structure my DB? Should I have it so that each page (or specific type of content) is it's own table and users are entered in to that table upon registration? Or is there another way to structure this that might be better logically and from a performance perspective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right path with user's groups. And to make a select each time user loads the page would give you a poor performance, but here's a solution I used once with something very similar.

First create a table that holds user groups (in case you need to add groups later), then add an index to your users table to reference each user's group.

Then on your login query select the user group's ID along with user and pass, and store it to a `$_SESSION` var as you would with the other two fields, let's call it `$_SESSION['groupid']`

Then mix php and html on your page where you want to show the right links. this part will deppend on how many groups you have, if they are few (such as Admin, Moderator, User), this should do it:

```
<yourhtml pre-links>
<? if($_SESSION['groupid']==1)
{
echo "link 1" //formated html links goes here, maybe pre-stored links
}
elseif ($_SESSION['groupid']==2)
{
echo "link 2"
echo "link 3"
}
elseif ($_SESSION['groupid']==3)
{
echo "link 3"
echo "link 1"
}
?>
<yourhtml post-links>
```

Hope this hepled you, don't know if that's what you were actually looking for, but this way you're showing them without having to change pages or anything

Comment: I would also go 1 step further by checking on every page if the current user may access it. So for example, a check on top of pageforgroup1.php to see of $_SESSION['groupid'] is in fact equal to 1. This will prevent the users from going to pages by simply typing the url.

Comment: This is perfect... it's more or less what I wanted to do - just a few tweaks to the structure will make it ideal for my need. Thanks Gonzalo Acosta & @Bjorn Smeets!

Comment: The only thing I'm not 100% sure about is how to reference multiple groups to one user? Would I need multiple entries of the same user ID but referencing different groups each time?

Comment: Well I didn't think of that. Are you doing that in order to manage several privilages? Or the links have some other use?

Comment: It's kind of both. Basically it's going to be a website with access to tutoring videos. Some people may subscribe to both math and science videos, while others just biology for example. I would need to be able to load the links/content based on the subscription type. Any ideas?

Comment: You should think about how many groups you're going to have. If they are few you can just add boolean-like fields to your user table, one for each section you want them to view. Else you can manage the privilage storage on your db on a single field, then explode it. Check this out in case you don't know the function http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Comment: I think what I will do is have it as a single table, with a column for auth_id or something like that and then for each course that's registered it'll go in as math science etc, and try to use the explode function to test it against the $_SESSION['auth_id']==math or whatever. I guess I might need to pass the data that's exploded into an array so that it can check each subject individually to make sure it's valid when it comes to multiple fields. Or, alternatively I can create columns for every course and have a boolean rule like you suggested for each type. Either way, very useful. Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about, I'm glad you catched it. The thing is, if you have many courses, use explode, if they are just a few (let's say up to 10), just making couple of boolean fields will be easier and won't give you big performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough knowledge in this. If I were you then,

I will create table with links

Table **links**

```
 link_id   link
   1       abc.php
   2       cde.php
   3       efg.php
```

And **user_details** as

```
 user_id username   password 
    1     login1   login_pass
    2     login2   login_pass2
```

and a table which defines user links as

**user_links**

```
  id  user_id  link_id 
   1     1       1
   2     1       2 
   3     2       3
```

From these tables, using joins I will get user links for login1 user link abc.php and cde.php

Same way you can map all other links.

For checking the user privilege, you can write a function to check selected path is already mapped with logged user ( user id you can store in sessions ).